# Pulling a Value from a webpage

Tags: delphi, soap, version

I'm wanting to pull a single value from a website, the page in question is just a file with no extension that contains a number, no HTML code - nothing.

All I want to do is get my program to pull this figure and compare it to it's own version number. What is going to be the best way about fetching this? I wrote a small snippet to download the file and save it in the temp directory and then processing the figure within the downloaded file but there has to be a better way if I'm not mistaken?

I have read about people using SOAP requests but I'm not sure if this is what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question. In your first line you says it's an html then you say it contains no html code. Do you mean you have a file with a .html file extension that is not html??

Comment: Apologies, I have amended my question and also changed my file.

Comment: You don't need any SOAP stuff if you're just fetching a version number. No reason to save it to a file, either. Show us your code.

Comment: Combine Andreas code with reflex and you are home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how to get a string from a HTTP GET request:

```
function WebGetData(const UserAgent: string; const Server: string;
  const Resource: string): string; overload;
var
  hInet: HINTERNET;
  hURL: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of AnsiChar;
  i, BufferLen: cardinal;
begin
  result := '';
  hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(UserAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
    nil, nil, 0);
  if hInet = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    hURL := InternetOpenUrl(hInet, PChar('http://' + Server + Resource),
      nil, 0, 0, 0);
    if hURL = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      repeat
        InternetReadFile(hURL, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BufferLen);
        if BufferLen = SizeOf(Buffer) then
          result := result + AnsiString(Buffer)
        else if BufferLen > 0 then
          for i := 0 to BufferLen - 1 do
            result := result + Buffer[i];
      until BufferLen = 0;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
  end;
end;
```

This is how my own software AlgoSim checks for updates. Try, for instance,

```
ShowMessage(WebGetData('My User Agent', 'services.rejbrand.se',
  '/algosim/update/ver.asp'));
```

Comment: OK, that `result := result + sth` is really ugly. I need to polish this piece of code some day... But for a string of this length, I guess it is acceptable...

Answer (score 5):

Delphi ships with the Indy components.  You can use the `Get()` method of the `TIdHTTP` component to download the file contents into a `String`, eg:

```
var
  Version: String;
begin
  Version := IdHTTP1.Get('http://url_here');
  ...
end;
```

Comment: +1 If there are no special reasons to use WinAPI directly, simple & concise solutions like Indy classes are better.